# После ввода в input страница падает

Tags: reactjs

в чем может проблема, пагинацию сделал, после первого рендера начинаю кликать 1,2,3 и т.д. соответственно все отображается далее когда вводишь данные в поиске все падает. Как я понимаю то что он не успевает перезаписать.

Классовый компонент

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _ from "lodash";
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import {fetchErrors} from '../store/actions/actionsErrors';
import TableSheet from '../components/TableSheet/TableSheet';
import SearchTable from "../components/SearchTable/SearchTable";

class AdminPageErrors extends Component {
    state = {
        dataErrors: [],
        filterInputData: '',
        resultAllFilter: [],
        sort: 'asc',
        sortField: 'id',
        currentPage: 0
    };
    nameTitle = ['Код', 'Описание', 'HTTPCode', 'Наименование'];

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log("prevState.dataErrors !== nextProps.dataErrors", prevState.dataErrors !== nextProps.dataErrors);
        console.log("prevState.dataErrors", prevState.dataErrors);
        console.log("nextProps.dataErrors", nextProps.allErrors);
        if (prevState.dataErrors !== nextProps.allErrors) {
            return {
                dataErrors: nextProps.allErrors,
                resultAllFilter: nextProps.allErrors,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAllErrors();
        console.log('this.props.allErrors', this.props.allErrors);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate', prevState.filterInputData !== this.state.filterInputData);
        console.log('prevState.filterInputData', prevState.filterInputData);
        console.log('this.state.filterInputData', this.state.filterInputData);
        if (prevState.filterInputData !== this.state.filterInputData) {
            this.filterDataErrors();
            // this.paginationHandler();
        }

    }

    inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };

    filterDataErrors = () => {
        const valueInput = this.state.filterInputData.toLowerCase();
        let filterError = this.state.dataErrors.filter(items => {
            return String(items.Code) === valueInput || items.Description.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput) || String(items.HTTPCode) ===
                    valueInput || items.Application.Description.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput)
        });
        this.setState({resultAllFilter: filterError});
    };

    onSort = (sortField) => {
        const cloneData = [...this.state.dataErrors];
        const sortType = this.state.sort === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        const orderedData = _.orderBy(cloneData, sortField, sortType);
        this.setState({
            resultAllFilter: orderedData,
            sort: sortType,
            sortField
        });
        console.log("sortField", sortField)
    };

    pageChangeHandler = ({selected}) => {
        this.setState({currentPage: selected});
        console.log(selected);
    };

    // paginationHandler = () => {
    //  // const pageSize = 5;
    //  // const pageCount = Math.ceil(this.state.resultAllFilter.length / pageSize);
    //  // const displayData = _.chunk(this.state.resultAllFilter, pageSize)[this.state.currentPage];
    //  // return {
    //  //   displayData
    //  //   pageCount
    //  // };
    // };

    render() {
        // const {pageCount} = this.paginationHandler();
        console.log('state', this.state);
        console.log('resultAllFilter', this.state.resultAllFilter);
        console.log('displayData', this.state.resultAllFilter);
        console.log('pageCount', this.state.pageCount);

        const pageSize = 5;
        let pageCount = Math.ceil(this.state.resultAllFilter.length / pageSize);
        let displayData = _.chunk(this.state.resultAllFilter, pageSize)[this.state.currentPage];

        return (
                <Fragment>
                    <div className="flex-md-column">
                        <div className="p-2 flex-md-grow-1 bd-highlight">
                            <SearchTable
                                    filterInputData={this.state.filterInputData}
                                    inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler}
                            />
                            <TableSheet
                                    nameTitle={this.nameTitle}
                                    resultAll={displayData}
                                    onSort={this.onSort}
                                    sort={this.state.sort}
                                    sortField={this.state.sortField}
                            />
                            <ReactPaginate
                                    previousLabel={'Предыдущая'}
                                    nextLabel={'Следующая'}
                                    breakLabel={'...'}
                                    breakClassName={'break-me'}
                                    pageCount={pageCount}
                                    forcePage={this.state.currentPage}
                                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                                    onPageChange={this.pageChangeHandler}
                                    containerClassName={'pagination'}
                                    activeClassName={'active'}
                                    pageClassName="page-item"
                                    pageLinkClassName="page-link"
                                    previousClassName="page-item"
                                    nextClassName="page-item"
                                    previousLinkClassName="page-link"
                                    nextLinkClassName="page-link"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        allErrors: state.errors.allErrors
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getAllErrors: () => dispatch(fetchErrors())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminPageErrors);
```

функциональный компонент

```
import React from 'react'
import {Table} from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSort } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const TableSheet = (props) => {
    const {nameTitle, resultAll, resultAllApp} = props;
    console.log('TableSheet resultAll', resultAll);
    return (
            <Table striped hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {
                        nameTitle.map((title, index) => {
                            return (
                                    <th width="10" key={index}>
                                        {title}{" "}
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => props.onSort(title)} icon={faSort}/>
                                        {props.sortField === {title} ? <small>{props.sort}</small> : null}
                                    </th>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {
                    resultAll ? resultAll.map((elementItem, index) => {
                        return (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{elementItem.Code}</td>
                                    <td>{elementItem.Description}</td>
                                    <td>{elementItem.HTTPCode}</td>
                                    <td>{elementItem.Application.Name}</td>
                                </tr>
                        )
                    }) : resultAllApp.map((elementItemApp, index) => {
                        return (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{elementItemApp.ID}</td>
                                    <td>{elementItemApp.Name}</td>
                                    <td>{elementItemApp.Description}</td>
                                </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            </Table>

    )
};

export default TableSheet
```

Прилагаются скриншоты
[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined]
[image: console.log]

Comment: А вы  `resultAllApp` в `TableSheet` почему не передали?